# comparing variables in powershell returns true instead of data

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to compare two sets of data and return all the ones that do not match i.e.

```
  $rrr = 'apple','tree','flower'
  $tt = 'apple'
   $yy = ($rr -notmatch $tt)
```

At the moment it returns 'true' instead of tree,flower. I have tried to use contain instead of match but to no avail.

All ideas welcome.

Thanks

Comment: `$rrr` and `$rr` are not the same thing. If that's not just a typo, there's your problem. Use non-trivial names and/or `Set-StrictMode` to weed out such problems.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
$rrr = 'apple','tree','flower'
$tt = 'apple'
$yy = $rrr | Where-Object {$_ -INotMatch $tt}
$yy
```

output $yy `tree flower`

more advaced

```
$rrr = 'apple','tree','flower'
$tt = 'apple','flower'
$yy = $rrr | Where-Object {$tt -inotcontains $_ }
$yy
```

output $yy: `tree`